# Use variable value as reference to function

Tags: php

I know i can use variable value to call specific function like this:

```
$this->{'function_name_' . $result['key']}->getMethod($someVariable);
```

I was thinking if I can do something like this:

```
$function = !empty($changes) ? 'function1($variable)' : 'function2($variable)';
$result   = $this->model_model->{$function};
```

What I want is if variable `$changes` is not empty i would like to call diferent function with different parameters.

I know I can use if&else but this seems as more elegant way.

Is it even possible to approach similar problem like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->model_model->{$function};
```

This says to look for an attribute of `model_model` with the name `$function`. It does not recursively parse the text in `$function` to see whether it looks like a function call. This does not work like copy and pasting raw source code.

What you want can simply be done with:

```
$function = !empty($changes) ? 'function1' : 'function2';
$result   = $this->model_model->{$function}($variable);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I need dynamically change parameters to function as well? Like for the function1 i need to pass $variable1 and $variable2, but for function2 just variable1, actually this is the problem Im dealing with now

Comment: Then you'll just have to use `if..else`. Don't try to shorten your code beyond usefulness.

Comment: You could store values in object variables on initialization in __construct method and then call them as needed. That way you can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func) function which is specialized for this task.

```
$function = !empty($changes) ? 'function1' : 'function2';
call_user_func(array($this->model_model, $function), $variable);
```

UPDATE : As per your comment, If you have requirement for different parameters for different function/method, then you still can use other version of function [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func-array) like that which use second argument as variables array:

```
$var_array = array($variable1, $variable2, .....); 
$function = !empty($changes) ? 'function1' : 'function2';
call_user_func_array(array($this->model_model, $function), $var_array);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn solve the problem when i want to call diferrent function with different parameters... I guess I'll use if&else

Answer (score -1):

normal practice is a something like this:

```
$this->model_model->m($param);
```

where $param is an object (as a [ValueObject](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html)) of specific types FType2 / FType2 ... etc. 
this is a best way for transfer between objects

but we know the PHP not supported overloading methods:

```
class Model
{
    public function m(FType1 $param){}    
    public function m(FType2 $param){}
}
```

However, we can do so:

```
interface IType
{
    //..
}

class FType1 implements IType
{
    public $param1;
    //..
}
class FType2 implements IType
{
    public $param1;
    public $param2;
    public $somethingElse;
    //..
}    

...

public function m(IType $param)
{
    if($param instanceof FType1){
        //...
        return;
    }        
    if($param instanceof FType2){
        //... $param->somethingElse
        return;
    }
}
```

*or something like that..*

Comment: write here if someone has trouble understanding... and .. call_user_func_array is not a best variant if it's your choice *!* thanks for your votedown